# Element API - Markdown in JSON

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

I'm a little bit stuck using the Element API. I managed to get my JSON file going pretty easily which was great but I've reached a point where I want to include some formatted copy as it would be output using markdown in a .twig template, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your Markdown text to HTML using [yii\helpers\Markdown](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-markdown), which is what the `|md` Twig filter hooks into:

```php
'transformer' => function(\craft\elements\Entry $entry) {
    return [
        'body' => \yii\helpers\Markdown::process((string)$entry->yourTextFieldHandle),
    ];
},
```

If you want the equivalent of `|md('text', inlineOnly=true)` (where only inline elements are parsed – no `<p>` tags), call `processParagraph()` instead of `process()`.

If you want to parse the copy as [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/), pass `'gfm'` as a second argument to `process()`:

```php
'transformer' => function(\craft\elements\Entry $entry) {
    return [
        'body' => \yii\helpers\Markdown::process((string)$entry->yourTextFieldHandle, 'gfm'),
    ];
},
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly. I got something close to this but was looking for helpers within Craft. Didn't think to use Yii helpers. Thanks again!